# XPage: when is the view scope lost?

Tags: view, scope, timeout, lotus-domino

when is a view scope in an Domino XPage application lost by timeout, when the page is not accessed anymore? Is there a timeout? Or are they lost not until the session is closed (because of a logout or of the timeout)?

I know, that there is the server page persistence configuration in the Xsp Properties. But when is the scope lost, if you do nothing in the browser? You don't work in other tabs, so that there are not too much pages. (Is there an event listener for that, that allows me to print this out?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK a viewScope object cannot live longer than the user's session. In addition it is bound to the current page's rendering for a given user. 
This basically means that there are three options to kill a viewScope object:

1. move on to a different page
2. ask for a *new* rendition of the same page (like re-entering the same URL etc,; in fact this is the same as #1)
3. terminate the session by logging out, closing the browser etc.

You might want to try youself by building some test pages with a computed field bound to a viewScope variable; make sure that the variable is set through a button or the likes. Another option is to implement the Xpages debug toolbar available from openNTF.

A very simple explanation of all 4 scopes can be found here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpages-scoped-variables.htm, but you might be aware of that already.